# Problem using ICSC (by majenkotech) in RS485 bus

Tags: rs485

I want to communicate with an RS485 Bus consisting of 5 Arduino Pro Minis as slaves and one Arduino Mega 2560 as Master. I found [a great library](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC) for this.

According to the documentation provided by the author of library I can use:

`ICSC icsc(1, 9600, 7); //ID, BaudRate, DEpin`

But I also have to define a Serial port for ICSC to work with:

`ICSC icsc(1, 9600, Serial1);`

I cannot mix these two sentences. I mean I cannot define both **DEpin** and **Serial port** for the ICSC in one sentence. But I need it to be defined. I don't want to use Serial for that, which I need for Serial Monitor. I want to use Serial1 for this. What can I do? I couldn't find any updated documentation about this.

**UPDATE**:

I found out how to define Serial port and DEpin for ICSC. The problem is I cannot get an answer!

Here is Master code:

```
#include <ICSC.h>
ICSC icsc(Serial1, 1, 7); //Stream, ID, DEpin

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  icsc.begin();
  icsc.registerCommand('R', &showTemperature);
}

void loop() {
  icsc.send(2, 'T', 0, NULL);
  icsc.process();
}

void showTemperature() {
  Serial.println("ACK");
}
```

And here is the Slave code:

```
#include <ICSC.h>
ICSC icsc(Serial, 2, 7); //Stream, ID, DEpin
String strAck = "ProMini2:ACK";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  icsc.begin();
  icsc.registerCommand('T', &sendTemperature);
}

void loop() {
  icsc.process();
}

void sendTemperature() {
  icsc.send(1, 'R', sizeof(strAck) + 1, (char*)&strAck);
}
```

Assume that there is just one slave and one master. I tried this code but got no answer. Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the constructors is out of date (I am re-writing as we speak, and is now [here](https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/ICSC/tree/master/docs)).

The constructors in the header file are like this:

```
ICSC(Stream *d, uint8_t station);
ICSC(Stream &d, uint8_t station);
ICSC(Stream *d, uint8_t station, int depin);
ICSC(Stream &d, uint8_t station, int depin);
```

That means you need to provide the serial object as the first entry:

```
ICSC icsc(Serial1, 'A', 5);
```

You need to manually start the serial object before ICSC.

```
void setup() {
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    icsc.begin();
}
```

This change was made to enable support for software serial and other Stream based devices.

---

Addendum for your update:

1. Don't spam the sending like you are. Send periodically, not constantly, or you will never be able to receive.
2. You cannot use String objects like that.
3. 1 and 2 aren't good choices of station IDs. Yes, they work, but not great, since 1 is the SOH character.

Comment: But what if i begin both Serial and Serial1 right after eachother ? Which one will be assigned to ICSC?

Comment: Whichever one you assign to ICSC.

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow and will let you know. Thx in advance.

Comment: Can i use this constractors in current version of icsc which i'm using?

Comment: That is the constructors for the version on Github.

Comment: Question updated :)
I followed your guides, But i still have problem.

Comment: Answer updated also.

Comment: Thx, I can now send and receive data, but i still have problem sending string to master

Comment: Never use String. Use `char *`.

Comment: However, with ICSC there is little call to send strings. It's designed for transferring numerical data from sensors.

Comment: Now im able to send strings over ICSC. I realized a problem with ICSC: When i disconnect one of MAX485s from circuit, No other devices respond to master! For example i disconnected just DEpin of ProMiniC and then i couldnt get answer from both ProMiniB and ProMiniD

Comment: Disconnecting DE leaves it floating. You have a corrupt transceiver on the bus. Nothing to do with ICSC.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the library notes a few different possible initialization methods:

```
ICSC.begin(stationId, baudRate);
ICSC.begin(stationId, baudRate, &SerialPort);
ICSC.begin(stationId, baudRate, &SerialPort, DEPin);
ICSC.begin(stationId, baudRate, DEPin);
```

So, if you need to define both a serial port and DE Pin, use the third option.

**EDIT:** Disregard this answer, as the library has changed initialization methods.

Comment: I tried that, but gives error: No overload method matches the (int, int, &, int) was found. Something like that :)

Comment: That documentation is out of date.